# Any idea about Exim 4 account auth settings

Tags: exim, email-server, lightweight

I work on a newsletter system for my project and I wanna use exim4 (lightweight version) for sending newaletters (just for newsletters because the mail is hosted separated...on google apps). But there is a way to auth and setup domains and accounts (mail@ex1.com, mail@ex2.com, etc.) ? 
Any idea is welcomed! Thanks :)

Comment: The answer is "yes" but without more information it'd be hard to say how you ought to do it.  Is this list going to change regularly?  Should mail@example.com and mail@example.net be the same account or should each domain be separate?  Are you going to have more than one account in a domain?  If someone replies to the email, is that going to be handled by this server? (if so, where does it go?)

Comment: yes...i want to be able to add as many domains and account as posible. if someone replies the email will be replied to a predefined email from google apps, that's why i want to use exim just for sending.

Answer (score 0):

Debian provides a couple of examples in their default configuration snippets.  If you're using Debian and its split configuration system, these should be in `/etc/exim4/auth/30_exim4-config_examples` (if you aren't, it would be after `begin authenticators` in the configuration file), and then you'd uncomment the section you are using (for instance, this one is for crypted passwords):

```
login_server:
   driver = plaintext
   public_name = LOGIN
   server_prompts = "Username:: : Password::"
   server_condition = "${if crypteq{$auth2}{${extract{1}{:}{${lookup{$auth1}lsearch{/some/place/passwdfile}{$value}{*:*}}}}}{1}{0}}"
   server_set_id = $auth1
   server_advertise_condition = ${if eq{$tls_cipher}{}{}{*}}
```

Note the `server_advertise_condition`.  Since the password is sent in clear text over the network, this login type should only be allowed when TLS is being used.  CRAM-MD5 does not send the password in plaintext over the network so it does not require TLS, but it does require the server to hold a plaintext copy of the password so it can generate per-session hashes from it. Per Debian's documentation, `/some/place/passwdfile` contains accounts of the form

```
foo@example.com:$crypt$compatible$hash:plaintextpassword
bar@example.com:$crypt$compatible$hash:plaintextpassword
foo@example.net:$crypt$compatible$hash:plaintextpassword
```

etc.  The crypt password hashes can be made using (for example) `makepasswd --crypt-md5` or `mkpasswd -H md5`.  The plaintextpassword is only necessary if you're using CRAM-MD5, since it requires the server to create custom hashes of the password for each login.  Adding and removing accounts is simply a matter of adding or deleting lines from the file.  Users must log in with the whole email address as their username.

Comment: server_advertise_condition is a boolean option, not a host pattern; the {}{\*} is working only because "" is treated as false and "\*" is a string with some length not explicitly detected as false, so is true.  Simpler to just write: `${if def:tls_cipher}`